# Spring Boot 2 + Cloud Finchley.SR2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Всем здравствуйте! Пытаюсь обновить проект c Spring Boot 1.4.x на Spring Boot 2.0.6. Но после загрузки зависимостей и некоторых исправлений, не внедряются два FeignClient с других проектах. Пробовал создать простой пример используя Spring Boot 2.0.6 и зависимости Spring Cloud Finchley.SR2. В примере создал простой FeignClient и пытаюсь его внедрить через анотацию @Autowired, но не получается. Появляется ошибка о том что такой бин не найден. Обшарил куча примеров и документацию спринга но не получается никак решить данную проблему. Помогите кто в курсе.

Это контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping("/example")
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUsers() {
        return "users";
    }

}
```

Это FeignClient:

```
@FeignClient("feign")
public interface ExampleClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/feign/example/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String users();

}
```

Это сервис куда хочу внедрить клиент:

```
@Service
public class CloudService {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleClient client;
}
```

Получается что в сервис не внедряется клиент почему-то. Хотя пример делал по документации. Непонятно.

Это pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudexample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cloudexample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

И сам main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class CloudexampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudexampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: приложите кусок кода, касательно вашей проблеме, в тело вопроса. иначе непонятно что не так.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Добавил.

Comment: попробуйте указать `@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"ExampleClient package"})` в CloudexampleApplication

Comment: Пробовал. Не помогает. Даже если конкретный класс задаю в basePackageClasses никакого результата.

Comment: в CloudService добавил метод `public String getusers() {
        return client.users();
    }`, в ExampleController добавил `@Autowired CloudService cloudService;`. в маппинг прописал cloudService.getusers(); и все работает. точнее нет сообщения о том, что не может найти бина.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Странно. Не понимаю в чем дело тогда. Можешь пожалуйста заархивировать проект и скинуть?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89004/discussion-between-senior-pomidor-and-alex-ciornii).

Answer (score 0):

выяснили, что проблема была в том, что Intellij IDEA "тупила" и некооректно показывала бины спринга. Обновили Intellij IDEA и проблема исчезла.